# Is Azure mature enough for actual production usage yet?

Tags: azure

I toyed around with Azure in January this year and though it looked great in theory, I wasn't even able to deploy a simple dummy application due to various bugs I encountered.

I'd like to have another look, however I don't want to spend another two days in vain. If you have recently tried Azure, I would be interested to hear about your experiences.

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: @AllenG: Good point. How can I make it community wiki? I've never done this before.

Comment: choose to edit your post.  There's a checkbox labled 'community wiki.'  Click it and save your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, Xbox Live, Microsoft's BPOS suite, Live Messenger, and more all run on Azure.**

If it can run Xbox Live, it can run your production app.

Comment: I guess it could do that half a year ago already. But is it stable enough for every day hassle-free deployments? That's what failed last time I tried, which is why I wrote this...

Comment: Yea, it's matured a lot.  Especially over the last year.  I would go with tgolisch's answer and only work with Azure in VS 2010.  There are lots of great tools that let you debug your application locally very well, as seamlessly as any normal app you would write.  Deployment to the cloud is still a bit of a hassle...but it is the cloud, and you do need to still jump through the proper hoops in order to make sure your app is setup properly to run on the "real" Azure cloud.

Comment: One thing to note though, I recently attended Microsoft's Azure Boot Camp and there was a lot of mention that Azure would be undergoing a lot of changes soon (for the better, especially around SQL Azure and adding more functionality).  So, while it's ready for production now, there will still be growing pains.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Azure for production stuff, and I've found it reliable, but pretty hard work.  Hard work because:

- The reference documentation is minimalist.  Many functions are covered by a one sentence explanation and no examples.
- While being much better than nothing, not everything that works on the development fabric will work on production.
- When things go wrong (especially when a role keeps recycling) it can be hard to work out what the problem is, although remote desktop can help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure works for us and allows to deploy [rather complex business solutions](http://abdullin.com/journal/2010/5/29/salescast-scalable-business-intelligence-on-windows-azure.html) with rather impressive auto-scaling capabilities.

We have already migrated all of the major projects towards Azure so far.

Answer (score 1):

If still in doubt, take a look at 50+ case studies [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/evidence).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 added a BUNCH of functionality towards Azure development. I think it is enough to move Azure up to snuff for production apps. 
However, if you don't have Studio 2010, I would wait till you can get it.

Answer (score 0):

Another example that I like (I was personally involved a teeny weeny bit so I'm biased :) ). All Twitter/Facebook results on Bing.com are piped through an engine that runs on Windows Azure. It consumes multiple realtime feeds and surfaces them on Bing. You can do the math on the scale since it is crunching on all of Twitter's data and has been doing so for months